# Information is not written to text file from twitter in python 2.7

Tags: python, database, twitter, tweepy

I have a project in python that I am trying to run from IDLE using Python 2.7 When I run the program a text file does get created like I want, but is not getting any information written to it and I do not understand why this is happening. I am running it as a module by pressing the F5 key in IDLE on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS laptop.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import MySQLdb
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Go to http://dev.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key=" # Omitted "
consumer_secret=" # Omitted "

# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token=" # Omitted "
access_token_secret=" # Omitted "

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# If the authentication was successful, you should
# see the name of the account print out
print api.me().name

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
        """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
        This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.

        """
        def on_data(self, data):
            print data
            return True

        def on_error(self, status):
            print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
        l = StdOutListener()

        stream = Stream(auth, l)    
        stream.filter(track=['#google'])
```

My file on github if anyone wants to work on it with me on github:
[stocktwitterdb.py](https://github.com/spsanderson/pull-status)

A streaming example using tweepy can be found here on github:
[tweepy streaming.py](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py)

Now that I have things coming across the shell I want to put them to a database or a text file.

Comment: In addition to the bare `except`, I'm suspicious that the file may not be closed and so output is never written out to disk. Instead of using a global file `target` (eww!), open it using a `with` statement and pass it to your class.

Comment: @Dougal when you say instead of using `target` that I should use `with` instead, how would I go about writing that? I'm very new to programming and do not know how to handle the fix you describe.  Thank you

Comment: One option is to add the file as an argument to the class: `def __init__(self, target): super(StockTweetListener, self).__init__(); self.target = target`. Then your loop could become `with open('results.txt', 'w') as f: while True: stream = tweepy.Stream(username, password, StockTweetListener(target), timeout=None); stream.filter(None, stock_list)` (with newlines added as appropriate). This will ensure that the file gets closed and output gets written after exiting the loop. Though I'm actually now less suspicious this is causing your problem, it'd be good practice nonetheless.

Comment: @Dougal I will try what you have written here tomorrow and report my results.  Thank you

Comment: Just bumped over the 5 minute edit window, but I should add that you'll have to change references to `target` to `self.target` in the class methods also with that approach.

Comment: I am now receiving an error that `self` is not defined just as I was getting `target` not being defined.  I am going to mess around with the file but what is in the editor now is exactly what I have in the file, sorry for making such a mess out of this question with stuff everywhere.

Comment: I have updated the code here @Dougal as you mentioned in a previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been some confusion in the changes you need to make, so I'm going to post a hopefully-fixed version here, along with some comments about why things are the way they are.

```
import time
import MySQLdb # also not currently used
import tweepy
from textwrap import TextWrapper # not used currently
from getpass import getpass

# define the format for messages here to avoid repetition
OUT_STR = '''
Status : %(text)s
Author : %(author)s
Date/Time : %(date)s
Source : %(source)s
Geo : %(geo)s


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


'''

class StockTweetListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, target):
        super(StockTweetListener, self).__init__();
        self.target = target
        # status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent=' ',
        #                             subsequent_indent=' ')
        # This isn't used in the current code. But, if you were going
        # to use it, you'd need to assign it to self.status_wrapper;
        # otherwise the variable would be local to this __init__ method
        # and inaccessible from anything else.

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            msg = OUT_STR % {
                'text': status.text,
                'author': status.author.screen_name,
                'date': status.created_at,
                'source': status.source,
                'geo': status.geo,
            }
            print msg
            self.target.write(msg)
            # use self.target here. self is one of the paramaters to this
            # method and refers to the object; because you assigned to its
            # .target attribute before, you can use it here.

        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
            # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
            print "Record Skipped"

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'An error has occured! Status code = %s' % status_code
        return True # keep stream alive

    def on_timeout(self):
        print 'Snoozing Zzzzzz'

def main():
    username = raw_input('Twitter username: ')
    password = getpass('Twitter password: ')
    stock = raw_input('Name of Stocks(comma seperated): ')
    stock_list = [u for u in stock.split(',')]
    follow_list = None # ??? you don't seem to define this variable

    # open results.txt here and name it f locally. once code flow leaves
    # the with statement, in this case only through an exception happening
    # that jumps you out of the while loop, the file will be closed.
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
         while True:
             stream = tweepy.Stream(
                            username, password,
                            StockTweetListener(f), # passes the file to __init__
                                                   # as the "target" argument
                            timeout=None)
             stream.filter(follow_list, stock_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit()
```

Comment: Big big thanks @Dougal I cannot try the file now since I am tethered to my cell phone which causes a 502 error. Thank you so much for the explanations as well. I will try it again tonight when I get home and if it works I will mark the question as answered. Many many thanks!!

Comment: With the `follow_list` maybe that is the same as `stock_list` I want to eventually use this file to pull in at minimum 100 different stock's at a time.

Comment: I ran the file in IDLE when I got home and the text file is created but nothing writes to it.  I have the code in the file exactly how you have it above. I went to the system monitor for my laptop Ubuntu 12.04 and looked at the Waiting Channel which read `inet_wait_for_connect` I have no clue what this means but its the only way I can kill IDLE is by killing the process. I asked what that meant in the Ubuntu exchange.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator I just tried running this, and I actually got a crash because `tweepy.Stream` got the wrong number of arguments. Looking at the source, it needs a single `auth` parameter, not a user/password pair. I'm not sure why you're not seeing that (an old version of tweepy?), but apparently Twitter no longer supports HTTP Basic authentication, and you'll need to do it with [oauth](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/oauth.py).

Comment: oh boy @Dougal ok. I have the updated version of Tweepy I did check that as I thought maybe it was out of date. I do a `sudo` update and upgrade every day and it seems that it is updating. What is your suggestion? Should I uninstall Tweepy and reinstall? Do you think that will get the newest version?  Thanks again for all your help I truly appreciate it. How do I go about using the `auth` ?

Comment: You could do `pip install --upgrade tweepy` to upgrade tweepy, if you use pip (not sure how you've installed it). If you have an old version, it might be trying to do HTTP BASIC auth (which twitter used to support) and hanging instead of getting an error for whatever reason. To do oauth, see [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) for getting it set up twitter-side and [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/oauth.py) for a tweepy example.

Comment: Hi @Dougal am presently getting an IOError 13 not having permission which is odd since I am the only user on the computer and noted as the admin...going to start checking on how to fix that issue so I can try the necessary tweepy updates. I typically do `sudo apt-get install` when I install something. I have `pip` installed but cannot make updates..looking for answers now.

Comment: Try `sudo pip install --upgrade tweepy`?

Comment: missed the 5 minute window @Dougal but I gained root access to my machine and did the tweepy update using `easy_install` I now get a new error message. It says that in line 75 `TypeErro __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments, 5 given` Thanks again!

Comment: Ok @Dougal I made a change to the code above to reflect exactly what is in my file and the message I get back in my shell. I also have a question now in regards to getting information from the twitter search, should I be taking a look at this do you think? https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator sure, that example looks good. Also, your edit from above about `self` is because you're trying to pass in `self.target` when there is no `self` at that point in the code.

Comment: ok @Dougal I will try to improve upon the file and see if it works I no longer see the edits above but that's Ok I still have the file just want to make sure you saw exactly what I have in my file. Also I cannot talk via chat because I do not yet have enough reputation

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Oh, I see that you tried to edit my answer to post a traceback. The error "read-only application cannot POST" seems to imply that your application is set up to be read-only (which makes sense), but the example code that you're running is trying to post a status update, which isn't allowed.

Comment: ok @Dougl I have updated the code again and I am getting a lot of info streaming to my shell but the text file is not being created, opened or written to, I will make another edit to the code you posted so you can see what I have and where I'm goofing up.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Don't edit my answer, edit your original question.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Your new code no longer has anything that actually says to print to the file: follow the line of execution through, and you'll see it never gets to `StockTweetListener` and never even opens the file. You'll need to modify `StdOutListener` to write to the file, like we did for your old `StockTweetListener`; you should also remove the `StockTweetListener` code, since it's not used anymore.

Comment: thanks @Dougal I'll try it out and report my success or failure.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this looks like a prime example for why it's a bad idea to do a bare `try/except`.

First, if there does happen any `UnicodeDecodeError` during printing, nothing will be written to your file either because that part of the code will be skipped.

Second, if any other exception were to occur, you wouldn't even notice it because you silently catch (and ignore) all of them.

So at least do

```
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print "Record skipped!"
```

and see which other (if any) exceptions might be occurring.

Comment: Thank you I will try these suggestions now

Comment: I made an update to the github repo and am obtaining a 502 error right now. I think maybe I should close my browser and try again? I'm a complete programming noob btw.

Comment: I am no longer getting any 502 errors as I'm now on wifi and not tethered to my phone. I changed the line to be written as you have it but still nothing is being written to the text file.

Comment: Are you getting any output to your screen?

Comment: I will screen shot my screen output, I am getting nothing to the python shell window and no error messages pop up.  I have to make the changes stated above for the `target` and others. I will work on that now and report back.

Comment: I am now getting an error on line 76 that the global variable `self` is not defined.

  File "/home/steven/Desktop/Twitter_Stock_Sentiment_Python_v_2_7.py", line 76, in main
    while True: stream = tweepy.Stream(username,password, StockTweetListener(self.target), timeout=None)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @TimPietzker I am getting nothing but an error now with the updated code telling me that `self` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import MySQLdb
import tweepy
from textwrap import TextWrapper
from getpass import getpass

qParam = "Twitter"

def __init__(self, target):
    super(StockTweetListener, self).__init__();
    self.target = target

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
    while True:
        stream = tweepy.Stream(username, password, StockTweetListener(target), timeout=None);
        stream.filter(None, stock_list)
target.truncate()

def debug_print(text):
    """Print text if debugging mode is on"""
    if settings.debug:
        print text

class StockTweetListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent=' ', subsequent_indent=' ')

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            # print 'Status : %s' %(self.status_wrapper.fill(status.text))
            print '\nStatus : %s' %(status.text)            
            print '\nAuthor : %s' %(status.author.screen_name)
            print '\nDate/Time : %s' %(status.created_at)
            print '\nSource : %s' %(status.source)           
            print '\nGeo : %s' %(status.geo)
            print '\n\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n'

            l1 = '\nStatus : %s' %(status.text)            
            l2 = '\nAuthor : %s' %(status.author.screen_name)
            l3 = '\nDate/Time : %s' %(status.created_at)
            l4 = '\nSource : %s' %(status.source)           
            l5 = '\nGeo : %s' %(status.geo)
            l6 = '\n\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n'

            target.write(l1)
            target.write(l2)
            target.write(l3)
            target.write(l4)
            target.write(l5)
            target.write(l6)                                    

        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
            # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'An error has occured! Status code = %s' % status_code
        target.close()
        return True # keep stream alive

    def on_timeout(self):
        print 'Snoozing Zzzzzz'
        target.close()





def main():
    username = raw_input('Twitter username: ')
    password = getpass('Twitter password: ')
    stock = raw_input('Name of Stocks(comma seperated): ')
    stock_list = [u for u in stock.split(',')]




    stream = tweepy.Stream(username, password, StockTweetListener(target), timeout=None)
#    follow_list = None
    stream.filter(None, stock_list)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        target.close()
        quit()
```

This is producing errors

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my comment (small space). The `__init__` method needs to be inside the `StockTweetListener` class; it's a method of that class, just like `on_status`. And the `with` statement with the `while` loop should go down where your loop was before, in `main`, because that's when you want that code to run; currently it's trying to do the loop before you've even defined the class, let alone obtained `username` etc from the user. Also, `target.truncate()` isn't necessary when you're opening in `'w'` mode, since the file starts off as empty anyway.

Comment: no problem at all, thanks for the help it is much appreciated, I will try those changes now and report my findings.

Comment: @Dougal I have the following:
`class StockTweetListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, target):
        super(StockTweetListener, self).__init__();
        self.target = target

    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f: while True:

    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent=' ', subsequent_indent=' ')`

Python tells me that `while` is bad syntax

Comment: Ok so I seemed to sort of fix this. I now am recieving an error message in the shell that the global name `target` is not defined. I am allowed to input a username and password and even input a search string, when I hit enter to process all that, that is the error message I am met with. *Scratching me head

Comment: The problem about "global name `target`" is probably because you need to change it to `self.target` inside the class methods, because it's no longer a global variable but a class attribute.

Comment: Also: in the future, it's better not to add answers that aren't actually answers; edit your question to provide updates instead. Adding fake answers makes it seem on the site like there are three proposed answers to the question when actually there's only one, and generally makes everything more confusing.

Comment: @Dougal I will make that change and I'll delete the answer I gave then? This way it cleans up the answer and makes it more appropriate?

Comment: @Dougal I updated the original question and voted to delete the answer I posted.

Comment: @Dougal do you think I should delete this answer as well to clean things up and just work off of the one up top?